# Как правильно запускать приложение SpringBoot(gradle) при помощи systemctl

Tags: linux, gradle, systemctl

Пытаюсь создать сервис, который будет автоматически запускать приложение на SpringBoot(Gradle) через bash скрипт. Создаю по аналогии из [этого](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64353905/running-npm-start-from-execstart-in-systemctl-service-file) вопроса. С nodeJS все шло прекрасно, а вот gradle отказывается работать. Подскажите в чем заключается моя ошибка.

*Все пути были проверены, ошибки в них быть не может.*

bash скрипт

```
#! /bin/bash
source ${HOME}/.bashrc

cd /home/valentin/Politehnika
gradle bootrun
```

Сервис

```
[Unit]
Description=rString backend
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
ExecStart=/home/valentin/Politehnika/script.sh
User=root

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

При выполнении `sudo systemctl status rString-backend.service` выводится следующее сообщение

```
× rString-backend.service - rString backend
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/rString-backend.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2023-04-27 10:01:51 UTC; 10min ago
   Main PID: 650047 (code=exited, status=127)
        CPU: 3ms

апр 27 10:01:51 rstring systemd[1]: rString-backend.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
апр 27 10:01:51 rstring systemd[1]: Stopped rString backend.
апр 27 10:01:51 rstring systemd[1]: rString-backend.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
апр 27 10:01:51 rstring systemd[1]: rString-backend.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
апр 27 10:01:51 rstring systemd[1]: Failed to start rString backend.
```